# как правильно подключить внешние скрипты в такую конструкцию

Tags: javascript, jquery

**нужно подключить bootstrap.js под версию jQuery 1.10.1**

**нужно подключить jquery.colorbox.js под версию jQuery 1.7.1**

```
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var $jq17 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
</script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var $jq110 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
</script>
<script>
    (function($) {
    //подключаем плагин на jQuery 1.7

    }($jq17));
</script>
<script>
    (function($) {
        //подключаем плагин на jQuery 1.10

    }($jq110));
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно загрузить вторую версию jQuery, используя ее, а затем восстановить исходную версию или сохранить вторую версию, если раньше не было загружено jQuery. Вот пример:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jQueryTemp = jQuery.noConflict(true);
    var jQueryOriginal = jQuery || jQueryTemp;
    if (window.jQuery){
        console.log('Original jQuery: ', jQuery.fn.jquery);
        console.log('Second jQuery: ', jQueryTemp.fn.jquery);
    }
    window.jQuery = window.$ = jQueryTemp;
</script>
```

А вот немного другой вариант.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>var $j_1_9_1 = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   console.log($().jquery); // This prints v1.4.2
   console.log($j_1_9_1().jquery); // This prints v1.9.1
  });
</script>
```

Вот и пример с вашим кодом.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
//не понимаю тогда, какое отношение к подключаемым скриптам имеет нижеследующий код?????????
<script>
        var $jq1_7_1 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
        //Эти две строки прописал для того что бы вы увидели в какой переменной какая версия ($,$jq1_7_1)
        console.log($jq1_7_1.fn.jquery);
        console.log($.fn.jquery);
        
        
        (function($) {
          //подключаем плагин на jQuery 1.7
          //initialize plugin 1.7.1
        }($jq1_7_1));
        
        (function($) {
          //подключаем плагин на jQuery 1.10.1
          //initialize plugin 1.10.1
        }(jQuery));
    </script>
```

Comment: Спасибо. А для чайника можно прописать - мне нужно подключить ВНЕШНИЙ скрипт scr_one.js под библиотеку 1.4.2,  а ВНЕШНИЙ скрипт src_two под библиотеку 1.9.1 Как это сделать компактно, не залезая в скрипты? Я в данном случае - про СИНТАКСИС

Comment: В своем случае я нарисовал такую конструкцию и далее в каждом из скриптов прописал нужную переменную jquery. Но это муторное дело - править каждый из скриптов, если их 20 штук

Comment: @Proshka Обновил ответ

Comment: еще раз спасибо - это все я уже давно сделал. Меня интересует возможность подключения внешних скриптов под нужную версию jquery. Может неясно выражаюсь, но нужно типа: jQuery1(<script src="src1.js"></script>) jQuery2(<script src="src2.js"></script>)

Comment: @Proshka Можете поменять вопрос и добавить примеры конкретные, с использованием кода внешних скриптов? Скрипты загрузите после линков `jquery` а уже инициализацию какого то плагина там где вы и в вопросе написали, под нужными версиями.

Comment: к примеру, нужно подключить bootstrap.js под версию jQuery 1.10.1, а jquery.colorbox.js под версию jQuery 1.7.1

Comment: @Proshka Написал в ответе.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71916/discussion-between-proshka-and-raz-galstyan).